# How to split tuple or lists?

Tags: python

I need to split tuple or list with numbers in left of comma and value in right of comma.

Code:

```
while True:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    now = datetime.now()
    currenttime = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    #print(currenttime)
    checkvalid = cursor.execute("SELECT `users_id`, `MutedTime` FROM `users`").fetchall()    
    print(checkvalid[0])
```

Result:

```
(212812894738448384, 'None')
```

Comment: What do you mean by split?

Comment: .split(",") use this function and search on stackoverflow resources are available

Comment: if you have a list then follow .split() method but if you deal with tuple the unpack the tuple.

Comment: Please provide examples of your input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
user_ids = []
muted_times = []

for entry in checkvalid:
    user_ids.append(entry[0])
    muted_times.append(entry[1])
```

should do the trick. Alternatively, use dictionaries:

```py
entries = {}

for entry in checkvalid:
    entries[entry[0]] = entry[1]
```